# member id stored as zero in expression engine session table

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, expressionengine

Some of the valid user sessions returning member_id as zero from session.

I have verified the entries in the session tables which shows that member_id is stored as zero against valid session id.

This issue is not generating frequently but in some user agents and sessions.

Comment: I believe guests, who naturally do not have a member ID, are recorded this way.  Or are you seeing this with logged in sessions?

Comment: Yes.I am seeing this with logged in sessions